# How to keep the aspect ratio of the image with given width in React-Native?

Tags: css, image, react-native, height

I am woking on an image Gallery. I need to show 3 images per row in a `ListView`.

```
renderCategory(category) {
    return (
        <Image source={{uri: category.image}} style={styles.image}>
            <Text style={styles.headline}>{category.name}</Text>
        </Image>
      );
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <Button title="Back" color="#5c6bc0" onPress={this.onPress}/>
      <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderCategory} contentContainerStyle={styles.list_view}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

What I have done with width is

```
image: {
        height: 110,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3 
}
```

Here I am hard cording the image height. Is it possible to adjust the image height with the given width in react-native.

Comment: You mean you need to keep the aspect ratio of the image with the width you give?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sample code:

```
image: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3 - 10 ,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3 - 10,
    margin:5,
    resizeMode: 'contain',

}
```

Comment: Can you explain the 0.7 scale factor?

Comment: 0.7 means 70 percentage of the screen size.

Comment: But I need relative height

Comment: the image in a gallery should have same height and width, right?

Comment: The image height should be relative to the image width.

Comment: This worked.
 image: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3 - 10 ,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3 - 10,
        margin:5,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    }

Answer (score 0):

For example, if your original image width/height is 500 px x 1000 px. 
And you would like to keep the aspect radio with a static width.

```
const radio = 1000/500;
const static_width = Dimensions.get('window').width / 3;

image: {
    height: static_width * radio,
    width: static_width;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: What if the source of image comes from internet, using `source={{uri: 'http://example.com/some.png'}}` ? We don't know the ratio of that resource do we?

Comment: @Halt in such case you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image

Comment: Thanks @IhorBurlachenko